# changing of label's text from appdelegate not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have created a function in controllerappdelegate.m like below

```
- (void) ChangeLabelText:(NSString *)SenderP
{
    TeenTaalViewControllerM = [[TeenTaalViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"TeenTaalViewController" bundle:nil];    
    TeenTaalViewControllerM.view.hidden= NO;
    [self.TeenTaalViewControllerM.lblLoopCountM setText:@"testing ..."];    
    self.TeenTaalViewControllerM.lblLoopCountM.hidden = NO;

}
```

note:- i wanna change the text of label from another view .For that only i have declared this in controllerappdelegate.

i am calling this function from another view like below

```
ControllerAppDelegate * TheAppDelegateL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[TheAppDelegateL ChangeLabelText:LoopCountTextL];
```

The function is getting called but the label's text is not changing .Please Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you have allocated `aViewControllerM` in appDelegate, before you call the line `[TheAppDelegateL ChangeLabelText:LoopCountTextL];`?

Comment: just a thing about naming... I recommend that you start your instance names and method names with a lowercase letter and class names with an uppercase letter. It helps make your code more readable.

Comment: yes @AlexCoplan
from now onwards i will follow these rules .
Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe  aViewControllerM  is nil .

Comment: but while i am putting po aViewControllerM in all output window in xcode its returning
<TeenTaalViewController: 0x4e366f0>.

Comment: or is there any way to check the controller is null or not ?

Comment: check if label is not nil , how do you create that label ? can you provide  more code ?

Comment: i changed the code..plz have a look at this and tell what i am doing wrong.